# ISP's router/modem sees devices behind my router (and other issues)

Tags: networking, router, routing, modem

There's my ISP's router/modem: 192.168.1.1/24
And my own router: 192.168.2.1/24

I have no idea what's going on other than misconfiguration... somewhere.
I had an EdgeRouter X, but it had stability issues due to age (bad persistent memory modules which degrade due to age) and now I'm using an Asus RT-AC51U until the new EdgeRouter X arrives.

Internet <-> My ISP's router/modem <-> Asus router

1. My ISP's router sees MAC addresses of all the devices connected to my own router.
2. I've turned DHCP OFF on my ISP's router/modem, it is ON *on* my router.
3. My router can assign an IP to a device connected to my ISP's router/modem and vice-versa if I turn DHCP ON *on* my ISP's router/modem and disable it on my own.

What's going on? Why can my ISP's router/modem see devices behind my router?

[This is from my ISP's router/modem. It sees all devices connected to my router on LAN2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8pRA.png)

Comment: The Asus RT-AC51U has a DNS server configured.  Is it's DNS server the ISP modem by chance?

Comment: Did you connected ISPs router into LAN port of your router?